# 2 AngularJS apps on the same website, multiple pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement [this](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) AngularJS/Bootstrap Typeahead app and also use AngularJS for search functionality as well. I have the Typeahead implemented and working, however I can not seem to figure out how to implement 2 AngularJS apps on the same website...?

Comment: this isn't really clear.  Angular Typeahead is a module, not an app...  why would you need two apps?  beside the fact that two apps isn't a supported configuration....

Comment: @Claies, ok sorry for the bad terminology. Based on what you said though, I should be able to do this if I include both a TypeAhead module and a Search module in the same app.... right?

Comment: yes, for sure, you can use multiple modules in the same app.  It might be easier to see what you are having trouble with if you provide a bit of code from your current setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first comment really helped because I didn't fully understand AngularJS, was just learning at the time. The first comment helped to realize my misunderstanding and gave the "light bulb" moment of just having 2 separate modules to include the functionality that I needed.

AngularJS - being modular - is great! You can really build capable apps using it.